# How to pass a Class as parameter for a method?

Tags: c#, function, class, methods, parameter-passing

I have two classs:

```
Class Gold;
Class Functions;
```

There is a method `ClassGet` in class `Functions`, which has 2 parameters.
I want to send the class `Gold` as parameter for one of my methods in class `Functions`.
How is it possible?

For example:

```
public void ClassGet(class MyClassName, string blabla)
{
    MyClassName NewInstance = new MyClassName();
}
```

**Attention:** I want to send `MyClassName` as string parameter to my method.

Comment: just create an object for gold class and pass it to function as argument.

Comment: I believe this is not a good practice to do, passing class names around as strings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function you're trying to implement already exists (a bit different)

Look at the Activator class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx

example:

```
private static object CreateByTypeName(string typeName)
{
    // scan for the class type
    var type = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                where t.Name == typeName  // you could use the t.FullName as well
                select t).FirstOrDefault();

    if (type == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Type not found");

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

Usage:

```
var myClassInstance = CreateByTypeName("MyClass");
```

Answer (score 25):

Are you looking for type parameters?

Example:

```
    public void ClassGet<T>(string blabla) where T : new()
    {
        var myClass = new T();
        //Do something with blablah
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could send it as a parameter of the type `Type`, but then you would need to use reflection to create an instance of it. You can use a generic parameter instead:

```
public void ClassGet<MyClassName>(string blabla) where MyClassName : new() {
  MyClassName NewInstance = new MyClassName();
}
```

Comment: Wrong answer...I Want to Send my Class name as string as parameter to my method

Comment: As a string? That's definitely not what you asked for... so, wrong question. ;) Then you would use the `Activator.CreateInstance(typestr, false)` method to create an instance from that string.

Answer (score -3):

```
 public void ClassGet(string Class, List<string> Methodlist)
        {
            Type ClassType;
            switch (Class)
            {
                case "Gold":
                    ClassType = typeof(Gold); break;//Declare the type by Class name string
                case "Coin":
                    ClassType = typeof(Coin); break;
                default:
                    ClassType = null;
                    break;
            }
            if (ClassType != null)
            {
                object Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassType); //Create instance from the type

            }

        }
```